# Is there any way to get a non 8-bit multiple data type?

Tags: assembly, memory, types, cpu-architecture, low-level

I understand that this is sort of bizarre question, but I have a few thoughts about and it made me interested.

example:
how can I get 31 bit data type or something?)

right now I think that the answer is a flat out NO, you cannot.
maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: You can always implement wrapping to whatever width manually.  Do you have a specific high-level language in mind?  Or assembly language?  There are CPUs with words and/or bytes that aren't multiples of 8 bits, e.g. PDP-10 has 36-bit words.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36-bit  On that system, the natural size is 36 bits, and 32 bits would be a non-standard type that requires extra instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have x86 architecture and C in mind, how can I implement this type of wrapping, could you please share some keys for google?

Comment: Like `a++;  a&=0x7fffffff;` to mask the result to 31 bits and implement an unsigned 31-bit type.  Redoing sign-extension to a wider type is more expensive.

Comment: @PeterCordes hmm, no this is not exactly what I was thinking about. could I have some kind of data structures that will be store in memory like 31 bit -> 31 bit -> 31 bit and can I made CPU work with them as 31 bit. so for transfer from one location to another it will transfer it like 16bit + (16 bit  with shift by one bit) or something?

Comment: my question have no practical purpose but can I really broke the CPU pipeline with some kind of esoteric data types?

Comment: No, you can't do that.  x86 has byte-addressable memory, not bit-addressable.  There are machines with word-addressable memory, but none I've ever heard of with bit-addressable memory where you could just do a 16-bit load or store that wasn't aligned to byte boundaries.  C with bitfields will emulate narrower types but with padding; you can't avoid having the compiler-generated asm touch the padding.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you! would you mind making an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always implement wrapping to whatever width manually, like `a++; a&=0x7fffffff;` to mask the result to 31 bits and implement an unsigned 31-bit type. Redoing sign-extension to a wider type is more expensive, typically left-shift then arithmetic right shift unless the source width is supported specially by the language and/or hardware.  (e.g. ARM has a signed-bitfield-extend instruction that can extract and sign-extend an arbitrary bitfield into a full integer register).

There are CPUs with words and/or bytes that aren't multiples of 8 bits, e.g. PDP-10 has 36-bit words. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36-bit.  On that system, the natural size is 36 bits, and 32 bits would be a non-standard type that requires extra instructions.

> could I have some kind of data structures that will be store in memory like 31 bit -> 31 bit -> 31 bit and can I made CPU work with them as 31 bit.

No, you can't do that. **There are no CPUs I'm aware of with bit-addressable memory.**  Any load/store has to be aligned to at least byte boundaries.  (Byte-addressable memory is nearly universal these days, but some DSPs and some older CPUs like DEC Alpha only have/had word-addressable memory).

C with bitfields will emulate narrower types but with padding; you can't avoid having the compiler-generated asm touch the padding.

e.g.

```
struct i31 {
    int i:31;   // note *signed* int
    // 1 bit of padding is implicit on targets with 32-bit int
};

struct i31 inc(struct i31 x) {
    x.i++;
    return x;
}

int extend_to_int(struct i31 x) {
    return x.i;
}
```

[compiles for x86-64 to this (on the Godbolt compiler explorer)](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5IILERyAgGo8AZlpKOAdj4AGAIJKjKlsorqOqvfu0ARS9Y4HZ8xSvUnkEFwrMeAHgCUmjpOhsb%2BAHR4/LFWYcZKxJgEYixK/g5hdtkGeKZKmP4EmCzoAPpE5fkE3nK%2B7hpBIdaJyanE6VEx8QY5BlKBjNIArFKkLNK646jSAMKxvErCYhKaXOrjBFODQwDWIKqqkQCcABy0tOe6Wly0WlrDUgAs4wC2dLq6Ezuks1LjQQgb7bKTTIZwWAwRAoVBvAAOeAYmDIFAgaARSJRICYxDeWlo3wAZkiSsQgRAAEa/Sn5XEAT2ktHGGLepQIAHkWAxGWDxlg3qxgMjfvhkoo8AA3TBAvmkIqYZAiEpM8Y1TAMX5yPAfKTMobMNgoRYCBh4SlAyBDVDwgh4VAsWUAWkF4gQllsuLekrOTqYShdRPhIg9LEwDoDbyJDFQTAIftpHoQuPQAYA6kwGAx0wHZOgPZxePx7gGOapAaJxJJaAbRuNJnL/voAEoAWSUwGQyCUWkiXEiGggLAdmGCEFwhBI63UpCUczhiORxGnNbnJq2O0C%2B0OtEiADZVGc7mdnhtnqoTuouE9XqQPiNvg3pn9pIDgaRQeDSJCYRjFyjyEoP8sWIEBgCPUgSQYMkKWpOVaRYBlVVIVl2S5HlRUwQU2BFOUxUVO1pVlZ8FSVFU9TVUwNS1YgdVVA0hWNIteEYc1LQga1bXtR1pCdMt00zBgK1WataykMYfkbaR/DOPcnT3Z4Oy7JQzj7JRx3wIhl24Gc5wXEDp1UYIFmYngNz5LdSAQTAmCwUCOJvd4QAfSTn3%2BN8QU3bd1H3Q9j1PVRz0vWhr01KRy1cmZXw/Tdv2hH8ICQYCl0A9F9KXFBDWASp5BYPZINJFFYJpOliF5ZkULhNlTHQ3lnwFIVcPqvBxUImVflI5VJAo8gqLC59tV1fVGEYws%2BBYs0LXgTi7QdZ1/G7J0CFxYAUiUL0fSYJ1hzDJ0bNpASs1LCKVirOgxIkp8oqkGS5IUpRkCy9T6jyscJy0ldZ3nTEl2nLhjPXGKLO855IluE490hs4TmeLQjiPEZHLvZzH1%2BdyhHfT9Bji%2BBEpAUQCGDAhUuS7F6EwTSSDoUgAHdiCYeF6KeS60ekHSNBpwgECUFt207bte37QcdtHczwSGazbOxBywtve9UakgEMc84HSAOQLIkPXQRjOVQH3PXXHjCiKrpfJWscssKuCcwkFbc6KLaGaVyW4kBniAA).

I should probably have used gcc `-fwrapv` to define the behaviour of signed overflow as 2's complement wraparound.  I'm not sure what the C rules are for bitfields, whether assignment of a signed result to a signed bitfield still triggers signed overflow undefined-behaviour in ISO C and C++.

```
# gcc8.2 -O3
inc(i31):
    lea     eax, [rdi+1]
    and     edi, -2147483648   # keep the top bit of the input
    and     eax, 2147483647    # keep the low 31 bits of i++
    or      eax, edi           # merge.
          #   IDK why it can't / doesn't just leave the carry-out in the padding
    ret
extend_to_int(i31):
    lea     eax, [rdi+rdi]     # left shift by 1 (and copy)
    sar     eax                # shift arithmetic right (by 1)
    ret
```

But ARM is neat and has better bitfield instructions than x86.  (Nearly everything has better bitfield instructions than x86).

```
# ARM gcc7.2 -march=armv8-a -O3
inc(i31):
    add     r3, r0, #1
    bfi     r0, r3, #0, #31    # bitfield insert to preserve the high bit of the struct
    bx      lr
extend_to_int(i31):
    sbfx    r0, r0, #0, #31    # signed bitfield extract
    bx      lr
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome answer!

Comment: there are many microcontrollers with bit-addressable memory. For example Intel 8051 has a special 128-bit region that are bit-addressable

Comment: @phuclv: and you can do byte or word loads from it?  Not just single-element bitfield stuff?

Comment: that 128-bit region is a subset of the address space, so you can still load a byte from it like normal. 8051 is an 8-bit MCU so it can't load any types wider than that